# Is there a way to gain access to the request object from an ActiveRecord callback, like before_destroy?

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to find out who is attempting to delete a particular record. I have a before_destroy callback in place that is preventing the deletion, but now I am trying to find out who is doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend this

```
@post.request = request
```

Then in your `post.rb`

```
attr_accessor :request

before_destroy :wtf

private
def wtf
  Rails.logger.warn "Person from #{request.ip} is trying to destroy, wtf!"
end
```